# jquery expand collapse efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, performance

I've just implemented a simple expand/collapse system on part of our website. I tried a couple of existing solutions but it just felt like too much effort to adapt the site to fit to it, so I wrote my own that fitted.

The code is as below:

```
function hide(boxtohide, boxtomodify, expandbox) {

$('#' + boxtohide).hide(300);
$('#' + boxtomodify).css('background-image', 'url("images/new/date.png")');
$('#' + boxtomodify).css('height', '69px');
$('#' + expandbox).show(300);

}

function show(boxtohide, boxtomodify, expandbox, origheight, origurl) {
$('#' + expandbox).hide(300);
$('#' + boxtomodify).css('height', origheight);
$('#' + boxtomodify).css('background-image', 'url("'+origurl+'")');
$('#' + boxtohide).show(300);


}
```

The logic behind is this:

- User clicks hide
- Content is hidden
- Contents wrapper is replaced with a thinner div,
- expand button shown in content wrapper (i.e. it replaces original content)

and in reverse for expanding again.

To me the code just feels a bit clunky, I'm not a javascript whiz so perhaps a little out of depth here and any suggestions are welcomed!

Dave

Comment: You might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only obvious change I'd suggest is the `$('#' + boxtomodify')` lines, which can be compressed to:

```
function hide(boxtohide, boxtomodify, expandbox) {
    $('#' + boxtohide).hide(300);
    $('#' + boxtomodify).css({
        'background-image' : 'url("images/new/date.png")'),
        'height' : '69px' });
    $('#' + expandbox).show(300);
}

function show(boxtohide, boxtomodify, expandbox, origheight, origurl) {
    $('#' + expandbox).hide(300);
    $('#' + boxtomodify).css({
        'height' : origheight
        'background-image' : 'url("'+origurl+'")' });
    $('#' + boxtohide).show(300);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could speed up the code simply getting each element first in JS, and chain those CSS modifications, as follows:

```
function hide(boxtohide, boxtomodify, expandbox) {

var hideElem = document.getElementById(boxtohide),
    modElem = document.getElementById(boxtomodify),
    expandElem = document.getElementById(expandbox),
    cssObj = { 'background-image' : 'url("images/new/date.png")',
               'height' : '69px' };

$(hideElem).hide(300);
$(modElem).css(cssObj);
$(expandElem).show(300);

}
```

Comment: Nice, will also implement this - Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I bet you're approaching this way too complicated, with jQuery you can do such things with a minimum of code, for example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ38R/)

```
$('.toggle').on('click', 'h3', function() {
    var $content = $(this).next('.content');
    $content.slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Nice approach, hadn't seen the .next() before and I think I could implement this. I'll get back to you!